# Unable to find valid certification path to requested target, when trying to clone a Java project from GIT to intellij

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, build, build.gradle

Trying to clone the project from version control Git. encountered the below error message:

> Gradle 'SeleniumTestFramework' project refresh failed Error:Cause:
>   unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Trouble shooting steps followed:

1. Gradle view refresh
2. Gradle settings as below

[image: screenshot]